# Wordpress isn't letting me hide a custom field in a div?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, custom-fields

This code must be used to output my images in a wordpress layout:

```
<?php 
    $temp_content = explode(" ",substr(strip_tags(get_the_content()),0,175));
    $temp_content[(count($temp_content)-1)] = ''; 
    $new_content = implode(" ",$temp_content);
?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
<?php the_post_thumbnail('home-post', 
                         array('alt' => 'post image',
                               'class' => '', 'title' => 
        '<div class="home_post_content">
            <h4>
                <a href="' . get_permalink() . '">
                    ' . get_the_title() . ''. $the_date .'
                </a>
            </h4>'));
```

I want to put `the_field('event_date')` in just after `get_the_title`. However whenever I do, it merely outputs the date either above or below the code, with absolutely no formatting around it.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a host of issues going on here depending on your css. Remember headings are block level elements (they take up a whole line) and anchors can be too. I would map out the html I'm trying to create and determine what needs to be inline and sort out the parent/child relationships. I'm not sure this is an issue with Wordpress output.

Post the html that is being outputted and the relevant css.

Answer (score 0):

You should return the value:

`get_the_field( 'event_date' )`